# How can I create different styled image galleries for mobile or desktop?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a quite simple website using React, and then using Bootstrap for the styling.
I have an array of data that contains the images I would like to display.

I want to be able to map through this array and on desktop show the images in a 2x2 grid, where you can click left/right arrows to see the next set of images.
Whereas on mobile I want it to just display single images where again you can use left/right arrows to scroll through the images.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

Just use Bootstrap grid system. There are different classes:

- Use `.col-6` if you want to have two equally wide columns per row. But using `.col-6` will produce two equally wide columns per row **on all devices**.
- If you want to have two equally wide columns per row **on desktop**, but only one column per row **on mobile**, you need to use `.col-md-6`.

*Note: You can also use `.col-sm-` or `.col-xs-` instead of `.col-md-`. These are all class prefixes which define breakpoints at which your content will stack vertically down. You can read more about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/).*

See the snippet below.

```css
.col-md-6 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-6'>1</div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>2</div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>3</div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>4</div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>5</div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>6</div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>7</div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>8</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```